# i can't start elasticsearch on docker in windows 7

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I want to install an environment that contains:
nginx
php7
ElasticSearch
MariaDB

I have already done pull & run
After I typed the command:
Docker exec -i -t dockernginxmariadbzodio_nginx_1 / bin / bash
And there I have the following error:

```
**Error response from daemon: / 33c92767302f_dockernginxmariadbzodio_elasticsearch_1 AS / dockernginxmariadbzodio_
nginx_1 / dockernginxmariadbzodio_elasticsearch_1**
```

After the passage on the forum I tested the command:
Docker-composer up elasticsearch
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKDE7.png)

docker-compose.yml

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  environment:
    - http.host=0.0.0.0
    - transport.host=127.0.0.1
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  volumes:
    - C:/dockerProximis/docker_proximis_zodio/zodio/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hdF7.png)

Comment: Refer this image,  https://hub.docker.com/r/nazarpc/webserver/  
kindly update the elasticsearch part in the docker compose file , as it contains image for nginx php and mariadb only

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing two things here:

1. Your `image` definition points to the Docker Hub image https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/
2. Your configuration `xpack.security.enabled=false` and especially `ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"` uses the one from Elastic's image https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker

Try:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.1
  environment:
    - http.host=0.0.0.0
    - transport.host=127.0.0.1
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  volumes:
    - C:/dockerProximis/docker_proximis_zodio/zodio/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:rw
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
In fact the problem was memory

solution 
1-Change default vm settings:
Remove the default vm

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count=2 --virtualbox-memory=2048 --virtualbox-disk-size=50000 default
docker-machine stop
exit
```

Then start open a new Docker Quickstart Terminal.

2-Modify the memory of map_count

```
docker-machine ssh
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
exit
```

After stop and remove the containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

docker-compose up –d
```

it's OK. :)